# streaming single audio to one user using wowza and flowplayer

Tags: streaming, flowplayer, wowza

I'm trying to develop a website with a music player in all the pages and music files for the user to select and play. When the user first selects a song in a page it plays as expected and everything is okay. But when he/she opens the website in another tab or window and selects another song it also plays while the other one is still playing.

Is there any way to play only one song even in multiple tabs or windows using wowza media server and flowplayer?

Answer (score 1):

well If you look at how sites such as http://www.reverbnation.com/ do thier music player you will notice that they use a wrapper div that has something similiar to JQUERY's Load(); function. So that the player will stay static and not change its content even if you click on an href. Try looking into this http://api.jquery.com/load/ and it might solve your problem.

Comment: thanks but the method you mentioned is applicable for navigating in one page. The problem is when the website is open in separate user's browser tabs. In this situation different musics can be played in each tab which is not desired.

Comment: Then maybe setting a cookie that the player is being played? that way if in the new tab they select a song it can read the cookie and see a song is being played and inhibit that player from playing? you could have the cookie destroyed whenever the browser is closed or the player is stopped.